# MySql select just one and order by date and blog?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I want to sort data from mysql.

The shema looks like this:

```
  id    int(11)             
  objectId  int(11)             
  type          tinyint(4)          
  field     tinyint(4)          
  value     int(11)             
  date          int(10)

id  objectId    type    field   value   date
1   1631    0   10  2918    1183  746534
2   1631    0   11      1108    1183  746534
```

Now My problem is I can't order by objectId and date 
Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by 'order by blogs'?

Comment: You need to make this much clearer. What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i mean order by orderid and date foreach orderid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order by object id first then date:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY objectId, date
```

If you want to order by date then object id:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date, objectId
```

To get the results in PHP in the same order:

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date, objectId");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
{
    echo "Object id: $row->objectId Date: $row->date\n";
}
```

Comment: this returns 
532   0   0   20   0   0
547   0   0   21   0   0

Comment: "SELECT *
    FROM rankingHistory
    WHERE objectId >0
    ORDER BY objectId, field, date
    LIMIT 30"
this gives me all the object id ordered by field date and objectId
now i want to sort that in php any idea?

Comment: That is already sorted... by date and objectid. You just have to loop through the result set to get values in that order. Check my response edit.

Answer (score -1):

if your dates and objectids are identical, it won't be much use sorting by them